# unity 3d How can i calculate the distance between the end and each player in a straight line approach, then sort them by distance,

Tags: unity-game-engine

unity 3d How can i calculate the distance between the end and each player in a straight line approach, then sort them by distance.

my code

```
    float closest = 1000; //add your max range here
    GameObject closestObject = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < MyListOfObjects.Length; i++)  //list of gameObjects to search through
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(MyListOfObjects[i].transform.position, winpont.transform.position);

        if (dist < closest)
        {
            closest = dist;
            closestObject = MyListOfObjects[i];
            closestObjects[i] = MyListOfObjects[i];
            //if (closestObject.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            //{
            //    print(MyListOfObjects[i]);
            //}
            print(MyListOfObjects[i].name);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can use `SortedDictionary` or `SortedList` for this. The idea is to sort after you've catalogued the objects, these types will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to order the collection by distance.

For Example:

```
var objects = new List<GameObject>(); // Collection of objects
var player = new GameObject();

// Sort object, It will return in typeof IEnumerable<T> 
var sortedCollection = objects.OrderBy(obj => Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, obj.transform.position));

// Convert your IEnumerable<T> to array or List as you wish
var sortedArray = sortedCollection.ToArray();
```